# How to set thousands separator in Java?

Tags: java, number-formatting, bigdecimal

How to set thousands separator in Java?
I have String representation of a BigDecimal that I want to format with a thousands separator and return as String.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This should work (untested, based on JavaDoc):

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(bd.longValue()));
```

According to the JavaDoc, the cast in the first line should be save for most locales.

Comment: Untested comment on this: Javadoc for `getDecimalFormatSymbols()` says: `Returns: a copy of the desired DecimalFormatSymbols`. So you should use `setDecimalFormatSymbols(theCopy)` after altering the copy.

Comment: The docs for bd.longValue() say "any fractional part will be discarded". So I don't know if this is the best way to do this if you care about precision

Comment: I guess you could use `new` and set it back to formatter: 

    `DecimalFormatSymbols customSymbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols();`
    `customSymbol.setDecimalSeparator(decimalSeperator.charAt(0));`
    `customSymbol.setGroupingSeparator(thousandSeperator);`
    `formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(customSymbol);`

Comment: I think you would want to use \u00a0 (non-breaking space) as grouping separator. It is the default for some locales.

Comment: Why do you call longValue? The question was to set thousands operator for BigDecimal, not long.

Answer (score 303):

You can use format function with ",";

```
int no = 124750;
String str = String.format("%,d", no);

//str = 124,750
```

"," includes locale-specific grouping characters.

[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: What If I want to use a `.` as a separator ?

Comment: As I usually use String.format it's the best and easiest for me!

Comment: @Enissay Call `format()` with an explicit locale (`Local.US` is known to use `,` as a separator) and then replace `,` with your custom separator: `String.format(Locale.US, "%,d", n).replace(',', '.')`.

Comment: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.lang.String arguments

Comment: @ImanMarashi Cast it to an `int`. Or a `long`. Or a `BigInteger`. And use f if you want to use `double`, `float` or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @Adowrath a `String` cannot be cast to an `int`, to a `long`, to a `float`, to a `BigInteger` or to a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @Pere I didn't mean cast literally, but just converting it.

Comment: Small word of warning: This blows up when using `Locale.ROOT`.

Comment: FYI… Alternative syntax in Java 15+ is available: [`String#formatted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) as in `"Result is %,d".formatted( no )`.

Answer (score 65):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(300000);

NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en_US"));

System.out.println(formatter.format(bd.longValue()));
```

**EDIT**

To get custom grouping separator such as space, do this:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##", symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(bd.longValue()));
```

Comment: i know i need to use DecimalFormatSymbols setGroupingSeparator, but i don't know how to apply it on my BigDecimal

Comment: @Funtime: you don't "apply it on your BigDecimal". You build a `NumberFormat` object with the desired properties and use that to format your `BigDecimal`. A `BigDecimal` only has a specified value, it **does not** have a specified format.

Comment: Note that the thousands separator is generally a non breaking space (when it is a space)

Comment: Had to change the top line in the 2nd option to DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(); for this to work.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using thousand separator for Integer data type use 1.

**1. For integer data Type**

```
String.format("%,d\n", 58625)
```

**Output:**

```
58,625
```

**2. For Floating Point data Type**

```
String.format("%,.2f",58625.21)
```

**Output:**

```
58,625.21
```

Comment: This was an epiphany. 
However, you really have to stress, that "," is only a flag, not the character it uses as a group separator. (Took me some time to find the issue.)
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 23):

try this code to format as used in Brazil:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(
      "#,##0.00", 
      new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("pt", "BR")));

    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(123456.00);

    System.out.println(df.format(value.floatValue()));

    // results: "123.456,00"
```

Comment: You too try this, in case of JasperReports, forcing the format correct:

`parameters.put("REPORT_LOCALE", new Locale("pt", "BR"));`

Send this parameter to report.

Answer (score 7):

```
DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
formatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('|');
formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

String strange = "#,##0.###";
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(strange, formatSymbols);
df.setGroupingSize(4);

String out = df.format(new BigDecimal(300000).doubleValue());

System.out.println(out);
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, the following [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html) gives you the specific country code to allow Java to localize the number. Every country has its own style.

In the link above you will find the country code which should be placed in here:

```
...(new Locale(<COUNTRY CODE HERE>));
```

Switzerland for example formats the numbers as follows:

1000.00 --> 1'000.00

[country code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbBSZ.png)

To achieve this, following **codes** works for me:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("de","CH"));
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
System.out.println(df.format(1000.00));
```

**Result is as expected:**

```
1'000.00
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public String formatStr(float val) {
  return String.format(Locale.CANADA, "%,.2f", val);
}

formatStr(2524.2) // 2,254.20
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer has to be really altered otherwise not working. The **getDecimalFormatSymbols** makes a defensive copy. Thus,

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(bd.longValue()));
```

The new line is this one: **formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);**

Answer (score 4):

```
NumberFormat nf = DecimalFormat.getInstance(myLocale);
DecimalFormatSymbols customSymbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
customSymbol.setDecimalSeparator(',');
customSymbol.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
((DecimalFormat)nf).setDecimalFormatSymbols(customSymbol);
nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

For **decimals**:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat dfDecimal = new DecimalFormat("###########0.00###");
dfDecimal.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
dfDecimal.setGroupingSize(3);
dfDecimal.setGroupingUsed(true);
System.out.println(dfDecimal.format(number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use underscore (`_`) to make **literal numeric values in the code itself** more readable:

```java
int example = 12_004_953; // Twelve million four thousand nine hundred fifty-three
```