# Java string number accuracy

Tags: java, string, numbers

How to decide number accuracy ? I am getting number accuracy from given string value
Example: 1202222  -------->>>> 1.202.222. First value are rendering to page 1.202.222

Using number accuracy

Best,

BG

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I think you lost a "thousand" somewhere along the way.

Comment: If you can't decide how accurte the number must be, how can we?

Comment: As one can only guess here, is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Integer.parse will give you 32-bit signed (about -4x10^9 to 4x10^9).
Long.parse will give you 64-bit signed (about -1x10^19 to 1x10^19).
BigInteger.parse will give you unlimited range.
Only use BigInteger if you are sure you need to handle numbers bigger than long because it is much, much slower and uses methods like add() instead of operators like +. You should rarely need it.