# How to convert Decimal to have thousands separation as space

Tags: java, formatting, decimal

I want to convert an incoming `Double` to String, where there is a thousand seperator.

For example 159727,5 should be 159 727,5

Here is my code:

```
public static String formatToHungraianNumber(Double toFormat) {
    logger.info("formatToHungraianNumber begin :" + toFormat);
    String formatted = toFormat.toString();
    try {
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("# ###,00", symbols);
        formatted = String.format("%14s", format.format(toFormat));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Runtime Exception", e);
        return formatted;
    }
    logger.info("Returned:" + formatted);
    return formatted;
}
```

Instead of return 159 727,5 it return 15 97 28
I had seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java), but I DON't want my result to be Truncated. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("# ###,00", symbols);
```

should be:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00", symbols);
```

The syntax of `DecimalFormat` doesn't change. Only the output changes.

Comment: I still get 159727,50
Instead of 159 727,50

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, it really works.
Thank you!