# How to format this string

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have an amount

```
Long amount=83000;
```

I need to format it to `$83.000`, how to do this ?

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));

String moneyString = formatter.format(amount);

System.out.println(moneyString);
```

I am getting `$83000.00` but i want my point before 3 last digit

Comment: no i want $83.000,if amount is 67890 then output will be $67.890 please help if any idea

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java look like duplicate

Comment: By *$83.000* you mean 83 dollars or 83 *thousands* dollars?

Comment: in us `.` is decimal separator and `,` is thousand separator, in majority of european countries is other way around. so if  you really want to display your number in europen format, try to use  `NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);` and then append your money string after you format your number

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work :

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("en", "US"));
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0", symbols);
System.out.println(df.format(83000L));
//$83.000
```

Comment: why the extra 0 in the format string? I thought that only made any sense when pre-prended to the string - assuring zero-padded values.

Comment: Without the extra 0, I get $8.30.00

Comment: Here point will be before 3 digit only but in this method point will be before each 3 digit.

Comment: $8.367.889 i got for 8367889, i want whatever the  amount it will return a dot before 3 digit like for this 8367889 output will be 8367.889

Comment: It became complicated ;)

Comment: Have you try it for amount greater than 100$?

Answer (score 3):

This may help you,

```
 DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.###");
 String output = myFormatter.format(amount);
 System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong class. NumberFormatter will give Locale specific formatting. From the API docs:

> Your code can be completely independent of the locale conventions for decimal points, thousands-separators, or even the particular decimal digits used, or whether the number format is even decimal.

You should rather look into [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) if you intend to output the same string regardless of the operating system's current locale.

By creating a formatting string such as `"$#,##0"` and passing an instance of [DecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) where you set the grouping character to `'.'` you will achieve your intended output without hacks.

Comment: @ToyOno has an answer below that examplifies this.

Comment: But for this number 8389000 its showing o/p 8.389.000,is there any way of removing extra dot after 8??

Comment: That is an additional requirement not present in the original question. It seems _very_ custom, and probably not supported by DecimalFormat, so you might as well just use a custom solution to it as well: Just remove the extra dot from the string manually.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
long num = 83000;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##,###");
String toReplace = df.format(83000).toString();
System.out.println(toReplace.replace(",", "."));
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you meant this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long amount = 67890L;
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
    String moneyString = formatter.format((double) amount / 1000);
    System.out.println(moneyString);
}
```

This code will print:

$67.89

Comment: ..notice that the question states that he wants to see `$67.890` (with a dot as the thousands seperator)

Comment: I know. But this might be a wrong decision so what I proposed here is the simplest and best and hence I stated: "Perhaps you meant this?"

Comment: I said "might". Sometimes people put the wrong requirements on technical issues. I suggested, didn't say. My solution is simple enough for one to consider. Just trying to help...

Comment: Perhaps you should convert your answer to a comment then:-)

Answer (score -2):

Use `BigDecimal` for formatting instead of `Long`:

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(amount, 3);
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en","US"));
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
String moneyString = formatter.format(bd);    
System.out.println(moneyString);
```

Comment: That is extremely inefficient, as you are creating a new BigDecimal for each number solely for formatting. Using DecimalFormat you can reuse the formatting in a much more efficient (and less hackish) way.

Comment: It's better, and I'll remove my downvote:-) but it does seem to be a roundabout way (especially since it uses FractionDigits).

Comment: @ljgw 3 fraction digits is not currency format for US locale, so you need to adapt the standard format or use your own pattern: "¤#.000".