# how to get the point to 3 decimal and in usd format in java

Tags: java

Hi here i have the code below to show a number into usd format

```
 Long amount = 1234L;
 NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
 String moneyString = formatter.format((double) amount / 1000);
 System.out.println(moneyString);
```

I am getting output as $1.23, but i need to show 4 also like $1.234,how to do this

I want my point to 3 decimal and in usd format.

let i am giving a number 150078 i will get o/p as 150.078 please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set thousands separator in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java)

Comment: why you open multiple question regarding the same topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338025/how-to-format-this-string

Comment: @DanP. this is really strange

Comment: @Leo obviously this guy/girl is working hard trying to receive "good reputation" ;-)

Comment: ... for someone else maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after you create your formatter:

```
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), check the link for further information on formatting patterns.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$ #,##0.000");

System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(3.114));
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(3.1146));
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(123213143.1146));
```

It produces the following output:

```
$ 3.114
$ 3.115
$ 123,213,143.115
```

Without the need for manual rounding in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
use DecimalFormat

new DecimalFormat("#.####").format(someNumber)
```

see http://rextester.com/NVUE17479

Answer (score 0):

please have a look to this tutorial from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

And the following code

```
        //Locale
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);


    dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###.000", dfs);

    return df.format(amount);
```