# f:convertNumber with input jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this piece of code:

```
<p:inputText  value="#{addnewfields.price}">          
    <f:convertNumber  type="number" />
</p:inputText>
```

So what I want to do is to display my number with space separators.

But still in my input it looks like `1000000` instead of `1 000 000`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5323547/2459449

Comment: Try applying this attribute to `<f:convertNumber>` - `pattern="### ###"` (There is a space in between). Note : I am trying to shoot in the dark. I did not try it myself.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution you can try is to create your own converter. The InputText value is a String, you have to manage the conversion from this String to the object number you want.

The converter has two functions to implement: from the object (binded value) to String (text shown in the input)
and from the String to the object.

You can see a converter example here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/