# Round number in java and add separator

Tags: java, rounding, separator

I would like to do this: 
if I have `1234.5678`, I would like `1 234.57`.
I have tried several things, like:

```
Object theValue = theValues.get(theHeaderName);
DecimalFormatSymbols theSymbols  = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
theSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat theFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00", theSymbols);
el.text(theFormatter.format(theValue));
```

But I don't manage to have the rounding and the separator.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java. It deals with separators.

Comment: Just use this as a format - ###,###.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you overwrite the standard format with `#.00` you have no grouping seperator in your format. For your expected case you have to include the grouping seperator again into your custom format:

```
DecimalFormat theFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00", theSymbols);
```

The pattern definition symbols can be found in the [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: Does the separator work for millions, thousands of millions, etc... too?

Comment: Sure. the default groupsize is 3 (i guess), but you can change it with `setGroupingSize(int)`