# Adding char in a specific string location

Tags: java, string

Hello I'm just a beginner in java and i have a problem adding a comma on a string of digits like for example 1000 will be 1,000 in output .

i can use :

`String digitsWithComma = "";
 digitsWithComma = str.substring(0,1) + "," + str.substring(1);`

but the problem is it only works on a thousand not on a higher digits. can someone please help me with this

Comment: You could use regex replace, but for better understatement, try iterating over the string and using a similar method to yours ;)

Comment: What's your intent? format a number?

Comment: Also, you might use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java

Comment: Seems a duplicate question, anyways, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format

Answer (score 2):

Java has a concept called Number Formatting that seems to be what you're doing:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
String output = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(1000000);
```

Since we gave it the US locale, it would print out `1,000,000`.

Generally speaking, if you find yourself wondering "how can I implement X feature?" chances are good that Java already has a standard or built-in way of doing it, especially if you're dealing with formatting of any kind.