# How can I do format a number to with dots

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I have a 5 digit number and I want to put a dot/comma in the last step of this number.

```
1234 to 123,4
2564 to 256.4
```

I tried this but it wasn't

```
int val=1234;
NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getInstance();
number.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
String output = number.format(val);
```

Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set thousands separator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java)

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to put `,` or `.` before the last digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're dealing with integers the easiest way achieve this is to just divide it by 10 and cast it to a double.

```
int a = 1234;
double b = (double) a/10;
```

This will turn 1234 into 123.4.

EDIT: This answer is based on your exact question. Putting a comma before the last digit.

Comment: Instead of `(double) a/10`, you can write also `a / 10.0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me.

Comment: How can I close the issue

Comment: You don't close it, you just accept the correct answer. Others might stumble across the same problem as you and will hopefully find this thread and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any character before last digit using this code

```
String str = String.valueOf(1234);
Integer position = str.length()-1;
String newVal = str.substring(0, position) + "." + str.substring(position);
System.out.println(newVal); //123.4
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you! How can I close this issue