# How can I achieve this programmatically in edittext view

Tags: android

[image: Check this image for reference]

I want to make "1000" look like "1,000" because I want to use it for a bank app balance

I want $1000 to be $1,000

Comment: Even though this is in java it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831492/15749574